# In a salesforce.com Flex app, how do I introspect fields at runtime?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, salesforce

I have a requirement I'm fairly stuck on and wonder if anyone has any suggestions.  I am building a salesforce flex application that needs to be able to connect to different salesforce domains.  Upon connect, I need to get a list of available objects and their fields.  From there I need to parse those fields into a series of components (lablels, data, etc).  I'm having trouble finding how to get a list of all available objects and fields upon connection to an domain, does anyone have any experience here?

Comment: Please be more clear with your explanation.  "Upon connect, I need to get a list of available objects and their fields." what does that mean?  How are you connecting?  What objects are you talking about?  Can you post any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code helps you to read all objects -

```
app.connection.describeGlobal(new mx.rpc.Responder(describeGCallback,sfdcFailure));




        protected function describeGCallback(result:DescribeGlobalResult):void {

                    for(i=0;i<result.sobjects.length;i++) {
                            objListQuerCreat.addItem(result.sobjects[i].name);
                    }
```